# linux disk utilization statistics, i want to track last 30 day logs growth

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, disk-usage, disk

lets say in /opt multiple folder and subfolders/files are there. I want a kind of statistics to see in last 30 day how was the per day utilization growth and in which file

any idea? apart from bash scripting

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like

```
#/bin/sh
du -s /opt/* > /opt/log/`date -I`
```

into `/etc/cron.daily/du-log` and do a `chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/du-log`.
I hope that does not fall into "bash scripting" for you ;-)